What does Oracle's ResultSet return on NUMBER columns?
What if a column is of type NUMBER, and I call getBoolean() on the ResultSet? What does it return?
The javadoc for the interface doesn't list the NUMBER type

java.sql.ResultSet
If the designated column has a datatype of CHAR or VARCHAR and contains a "0" or has a datatype of BIT, TINYINT, SMALLINT, INTEGER or BIGINT and contains a 0, a value of false is returned. If the designated column has a datatype of CHAR or VARCHAR and contains a "1" or has a datatype of BIT, TINYINT, SMALLINT, INTEGER or BIGINT and contains a 1, a value of true is returned

The doc for Oracle's extension doesn't elaborate
Java 8
JDBC Driver version com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc6:11.2.0.4
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
UPD
Is this the thing? IDE doesn't download the sources for some reason so I figure it's as far as we can go. I don't get what this code does
// oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor#getBoolean
    boolean getBoolean(int var1) throws SQLException {
        boolean var2 = false;
        if (this.rowSpaceIndicator == null) {
            SQLException var6 = DatabaseError.createSqlException(this.getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(), 21);
            var6.fillInStackTrace();
            throw var6;
        } else {
            if (this.rowSpaceIndicator[this.indicatorIndex + var1] != -1) {
                byte[] var3 = this.rowSpaceByte;
                int var4 = this.columnIndex + this.byteLength * var1 + 1;
                byte var5 = var3[var4 - 1];
                var2 = var5 != 1 || var3[var4] != -128;
            }

            return var2;
        }
    }


You may say it's a bad idea to rely on undocumented behavior anyway, but I do find getBoolean() to be more semantically appealing. It's not that any sane person at Oracle would change that behavior, whatever it is, even if it's undocumented. Pretty unthinkable

"You may say it's a bad idea to rely on undocumented behavior anyway, but I do find getBoolean() to be more semantically appealing." - If I was reading your code, I wouldn't.  Hint: its not just what you find "semantically appealing" that matters.  Consider what happens when someone else comes across some of your code where you are calling getBoolean on a NUMBER column, and they have the same "doubts" that you had.  What do they do?  They go down the rabbit hole of looking at the javadocs, Googling, asking an SO question and so on.   Isn't it better to avoid that?

You should try it and add the results to your question.

related (highly active question) Is there any boolean type in Oracle databases?

from Oracle's JDBC Developer's Guide 11 Accessing and Manipulating Oracle Data: "The getBoolean method is supported only for numeric columns. When applied to these columns, getBoolean interprets any zero value as false and any other value as true."

almost same for Oracle 11: link

From the Oracle 11g JDBC Developer's Guide: 11 Accessing and Manipulating Oracle Data

getBoolean
Because there is no BOOLEAN database type, when you use getBoolean a data type conversion always occurs. The getBoolean method is supported only for numeric columns. When applied to these columns, getBoolean interprets any zero value as false and any other value as true. When applied to any other sort of column, getBoolean raises the exception java.lang.NumberFormatException.

The corresponding Oracle 23ai JDBC Developer's Guide: 12 Accessing and Manipulating Oracle Data was updated to include the BOOLEAN column type, otherwise, for numeric columns, nothing changed.
Note: The best way may be to test the behaviour using your driver (and then add an integration test to your test suite so that you can track any changes to the behaviour if you upgrade drivers). Else, upgrade to a modern, supported database version.

by the way, the Oracle 11 JDBC Guide is the oldest available on the normal Oracle database documentation pages (easy to find once you are used to the documentation system used by Oracle)
